# Scipy interp1d and matlab interp1

Tags: matlab, scipy, interpolation

The following are the inputs for my interpolation:

```
x = [-1.01, 5.66, 5.69, 13.77, 20.89]

y = [0.28773, 1.036889, 1.043178, 1.595322, 1.543763]

new_x = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]
```

The results from `matlab` `interp1` and `scipy.interpolate` `interp1d` are different.
The results are like this.

```
new_y_scipy=[0.401171, 0.625806, 0.850442, 1.062384, 1.186291, 1.248244, 1.310198, 1.372152, 1.434105, 1.496059, 1.545429, 1.55267, 1.559911, 1.567153, 1.574394, 1.588877,]

new_y_matlab=[0.401171, 0.625806, 0.850442, 1.064362, 1.201031, 1.269366, 1.3377, 1.406035, 1.47437, 1.542704, 1.593656, 1.586415, 1.579174, 1.571932, 1.564691, 1.550208]
```

Apparently `matlab` seems to get better result than `scipy`. What is the fundamental difference?

Comment: My scipy results match your matlab results: `np.allclose(new_y_matlab, interp1d(x,y)(new_x))`
`True`

Comment: Hi @askewchan, what does np.allclose does? what is the difference in not using it?

Comment: `np.allclose` just checks to see if two arrays are the same, here it returns `True`.  The point is that I think you have a mistake in your use of `scipy`, because when I use `scipy` I get the same results that you do in `matlab`, see my answer for more info.

Comment: the way i wrote the code is 'set_intep=interp1d(x,y,kind='linear') new_y=set_intep(new_x)' i get a different value. Why?

Comment: That still gives the same thing for me.  Are you sure that your `x` and `y` arrays match?  From the plot I made, it almost looks like the last two values in your `y` array got swapped :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that your data from `scipy` might be messed up somehow, because I can't reproduce your problem.  For me, the results from `scipy` match perfectly with your results from `matlab`.  See below for a demonstration:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-1.01, 5.66, 5.69, 13.77, 20.89]
y = [0.28773, 1.036889, 1.043178, 1.595322, 1.543763]

new_x = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]
new_y_scipy=[0.401171, 0.625806, 0.850442, 1.062384, 1.186291, 1.248244, 1.310198, 1.372152, 1.434105, 1.496059, 1.545429, 1.55267, 1.559911, 1.567153, 1.574394, 1.588877,]
new_y_matlab=[0.401171, 0.625806, 0.850442, 1.064362, 1.201031, 1.269366, 1.3377, 1.406035, 1.47437, 1.542704, 1.593656, 1.586415, 1.579174, 1.571932, 1.564691, 1.550208]

askewchan = interp1d(x,y)(new_x)

# 'linear' has no effect since it's the default, but I'll plot it too:
set_interp = interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')
new_y = set_interp(new_x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', new_x, new_y_scipy, '--', new_x, new_y_matlab, ':', new_x, askewchan, '.', new_x, new_y, '+')
plt.legend(('Original','OP_scipy', 'OP_matlab', 'askewchan_scipy', 'OP style scipy'), loc='lower right')

np.allclose(new_y_matlab, interp1d(x,y)(new_x))
#True
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks there was some rounding off errors in the original array for me. that is why the error get accumulated.